# resize subview after resizing tab bar swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'm working with a UIViewController which inherits a tab bar from a TabBarController, within it, I have a UITableView with its bottom space set to be equal to bottom layout guide top, which looks like this:

[image]

then I used this code to resize my tab bar

```
let barHeight: CGFloat = 40.0

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    var tabFrame = tabBar.frame
    tabFrame.size.height = barHeight
    tabFrame.origin.y = view.frame.size.height - barHeight - 1
    tabBar.frame = tabFrame
}
```

but it seems like the table view has already been laid out before the tab bar is resized and it results in something like this

[image]

Is there any way to resize the subview dynamically so that it still follows the same layout?

Comment: 1. Add a height constraint to your `TabBar` or
2. Change `TabBar` height in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Why would you want to change `TabBar` height in first place?

Comment: how did your output like this?? show me full code. i tried and it's working fine for me just your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me

```
extension UITabBar {
    override open func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        var sizeThatFits = super.sizeThatFits(size)
        sizeThatFits.height = 40

        return sizeThatFits
    }
}
```